# "Intercept" Windows shut down and execute a command

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

Basic informations:

language is c++ (visual c++ 2013).
my program is a win32 application, multithreaded (3 threads) and for its design it runs as critical process (using RtlSetProcessIsCritical, it does the job). I can programmatically turn it on and  off (two functions, one sets the current process to critical, the second turns the current process back to non-critical).

if i simply click start-->shut down windows the system obviously crashes with a bsod, the same bsod you get if you terminate manually a critical process.

how can i detect when windows is shutting down/restarting? so i can execute the "turn to non-critical" function, resulting in a clean shut down. :)

one of the threads consist of a loop that runs every 5 or 10 seconds, adding the windows shutdown detection in here sounds the only viable option.

i tried only one thing, WM_ENDSESSION as shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. but it "fails" to detect the os shutdown, and it ends up with a bsod.

i would find some examples or informations very useful. if additionals details are needed let me know, i will have access to the computer where my program is stored in a couple of hours.
thank you.

edit: why downvote? im learning and wanted to ask about something i cant fix.

edit: could you provide an example of where/how to add the actual checking for the message in my loop? i cant get over this, ive got already the case WM_QUERYENDSESSION in the switch statement.. thank you.

---------------EDIT:

i cant get it to work, no matter what i try it wont work..
my program in pseudocode:

```
thread 1
 { 
  functionx();
  functiony();
 }


thread 2
 {
  functionz();
  functionf();
 }


thread 3
 {
   for (;;)
    {
      functiong();
      functionh();
    }
 }

int main()
 {
   thread 1;
   thread 2;
   thread 3;
 }
```

for the GetMessage part ive used the code from here http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/window_click.html and re-adjusted to fit my needs:

```
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
        function_to_turn_critical_process_OFF();
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_ENDSESSION:
        function_to_turn_critical_process_OFF();
        return 0;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
```

ok, if i insert the message loop in main() as the first thing executed i run into problem number 1, GetMessage seems to put the whole thing to sleep, so my program doesnt even start doing his stuff.

if i insert the message loop in main() as the last thing executed (under thread 3) i run into problem number 2, since thread 3 never ends (loops forever) the message loop probably never starts. Also, the thread 3 loop contains a little Sleep for a couple of seconds, ive tried to put the get message loop in there but it fails to catch it, i cant remove the original code, cant change loops or delete the little sleep function.

if i insert the message loop in the thread 3 loop it just fails to detect WM_QUERYENDSESSION and i end up with a BSOD on windows shut down, so my "turn critical off" function is not being executed.

what can i do? google is not helping about this particular thing. i know that in a simple program im supposed to put the message loop in main and it will work for last, but im going nuts here trying to find a place in my code for this message loop.

any help is appreciated..

Comment: Are you getting any messages in your message loop? The WM_QUERY_ENDSESSION message answer below is correct. Your program main should create a window, start your worker threads, and then do the message processing loop. When you handle WM_ENDSESSION, change the app priority, and maybe signal the threads to end gracefully (SetEvent or something similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two messages that windows send to an application: [WM_QUERY_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85).aspx)

you can react to them exiting the application gracefully.

In your case, WM_ENDSESSION happens probably too late to let you change the app priority.

In WM_QUERY_ENDSESSION the system is not yet shutting down. So you can adjust your settings and then return "*Yes, of course!*".